# Django form errors printed

Tags: python, django, forms, error-handling

I've got a dictionary containing form errors, namely:

```
[u'PHONE_ALREADY_REGISTERED', u'EMAIL_ALREADY_REGISTERED!']
```

How can I access the values from the dictionary and print them as strings on the screen? This is the piece of HTML code I'm using up until now:

```
{% if errors %}
    {{ errors.values }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, that's *not* a dictionary. It's a list.

Second the way to print the values of any iterable (dictionaries and lists, included) is with a for loop.

```
{% if errors %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In your view you could use something like `u', '.join(errors)` to transform the list into a single string, but you can't use code like that in a Django template.